# Dart: Timer.periodic not honoring granularity of duration in VM

Tags: timer, dart

This may or may not be a bug, but I would like some help understanding the behavior of Timer.

Here is a test program that sets up Timer.periodic with a duration of 1000 microseconds (1 millisecond). The callback that fires increments a count. Once the count reaches 1000 intervals, the program prints the time elapsed and exits. The point being to get close to 1 second in execution time. Consider the following:

```
import 'dart:async'

main() {
    int count = 0;
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.start();
    new Timer.periodic(new Duration(microseconds:  1000), (Timer t) {
       count++;
       if(count == 1000){
          print(stopwatch.elapsed);
          stopwatch.stop();
       }
});
```

The result is:

```
0:00:01.002953
```

That is, just over a second (assuming the remainder is coming from start time of the stopwatch).

However, if you change the resolution to be anything under 1 millisecond e.g. 500 microseconds, the Timer seems to ignore the duration entirely and executes as quickly as possible.

Result being:

```
0:00:00.008911
```

I would have expected this to be closer to half a second. Is this an issue with the granularity of the Timer? This issue can also be observed when applying a similar scenario to Future.delayed

Comment: Are you testing in a console app running in the Dart VM, or a web-app compiled to Javascript?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus This is a console app running in the Dart VM, so I shouldn't be hitting the 4 millisecond issue seen when compiling to Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal resolution of the timer is 1ms. When asking for a 500ns duration is rounded to 0ms, aka: as fast as possible. 
The code is:

```
int milliseconds = duration.inMilliseconds;
if (milliseconds < 0) milliseconds = 0;
return _TimerFactory._factory(milliseconds, callback, true);
```

Maybe it should take 1ms as a minimum, if that is its actual minimum, or it should handle microseconds internally, even if it only triggers every 10-15 milliseconds and runs the events pending so far.

Comment: This should be documented in the Dartdoc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I definitely agree the Dartdoc should make this a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in VM it looks like a bug. Please [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new).

If you are in JS side see the following note on the documentation of the [Timer](https://api.dartlang.org/1.13.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html) class:

> Note: If Dart code using Timer is compiled to JavaScript, the finest granularity available in the browser is 4 milliseconds.

Comment: This is a console app running in the Dart VM so the above note shouldn't apply. Sorry for not being more clear.